# how to enable webgl2 on webview on android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webgl2

I'm currently using android studio 2.3.3 and need to build a tool that loads a webpage that renders a 3D model internally in the app from the website that my company uses. .

I have built the webview client and can load the page, but it shows a warning saying that the browser cannot render the file - which in the website is launched whenever the browser doesn't have webgl2 support.

My webview:

```
    web = (WebView)findViewById(webview);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                web.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(web, url);
                web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    web.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

The webview seems to be working fine. I just need to know if there's a way to enable webgl2 in it in order to render the 3D models. I can open the url in a browser in the emulator and it works fine, but what I need is to do so from inside the app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as far as i know its not supportted by native android webView. might be helpful using crossWalk project

Comment: thank you @AkashPal; This was a code problem on my end. WebGl is supported by modern android and you don't need crosswalk anymore for it.

Comment: @HeltonMatiazi how did you get WebGL 2 working in the end?

Comment: @HeltonMatiazi hi, i try but still can not do that, how it work? thanks

Comment: @mortezamoradi, webgl2 is suported natively on modern webviews. You need to make sure that your device is up to date.  I had some trouble making it work on android emulators but it was mainly due to local configuration. If you are having problems with a similar issue you might want to share your code so we can figure out what is being done differently :)